# Webflow view-state model bean properties are not autowired

Tags: spring-webflow-2

I have a Spring 3.2.11 and Webflow 2.4.0 app using JSF2 for view rendering.

One of my pages uses a view-state model bean for validation but when the validatePasswordChange method is called, the bean properties have not been autowired so I get a NPE. I don't understand why they're null!?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Here's my bean validation method. Why is the passwordService property null?

```
public void validatePasswordChange(ValidationContext context) {

    MessageContext messages = context.getMessageContext();
    if (!confirmPassword.equals(newPassword)) {

        messages.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().error()
                .source("confirmPassword")
                .defaultText(
                        this.getMessage("kyn.password.change.validation.noMatch"))
                .build());
    };

    List<String> validationMessages = passwordService
            .validatePasswordPolicyCompliance(getUsername(),
            newPassword);
    if (validationMessages != null) {
        for (String message : validationMessages) {
            messages.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().error()
                    .source("confirmPassword")
                    .defaultText(message).build());
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet from my flow.xml. I'm inserting passwordUpdateBean into the flowScope in the on-start and expecting the model attribute to use it:

```
<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="passwordUpdateBean" result="flowScope.passwordUpdateBean"></evaluate>
</on-start>

<view-state id="passwordChange" model="passwordUpdateBean">
    <transition on="proceed" to="update"/>
    <transition on="cancel" to="redirectCancel"  validate="false"/>
</view-state>
```

And here's my bean config xml:

```
<bean id="passwordUpdateBean"
    class="com.xyz.PasswordUpdateBean"
    scope="prototype"
    parent="abstractWebBean">
    <property name="passwordService" ref="passwordManagementService"/>  
    <property name="appUserDetailsService" ref="appUserDetailsService"/>
    <property name="autoLoginAfterEnrollment" value="true"/>
    <property name="usernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider" ref="usernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

beans **will NOT** auto wire inside your flow definitions. You have get have to explicitly retrieve the bean into the flow definition.

Note **@Service** class annotations are automatically accessible in flow files `(i.e <evaluate expression="myService.getPasswordUpdateBean()" result="flowScope.passwordUpdateBean"/>)`

```
<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="....getPasswordUpdateBean()" result="flowScope.passwordUpdateBean"></evaluate>
    <!-- where '....' = either @service class or some other obj that holds a reference to the bean you seek --> 
</on-start>
```